# "Base SDK Missing" after upgrading to Xcode 3.2.5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios4

So I took the step upgrading to Xcode 3.2.5 (iPhone SDK 4.2) and now I cannot run to device. I always see this now in the dev environment:

[image]

In my current projects, when going to the project settings I can only set the Base SDK to iOS 4.2 but this doesn't change the "Base SDK Missing" problem. :/

I can however deploy to the simulator, and change which version I want the simulator to load as.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

If I create a new project I don't get this...

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved this problem, by doing this:

```
Project->Edit Project Settings->Build->Base SDK->Latest SDK (4.2)
Project->Edit Project Settings->Build->iOS Target Deployment->iOS 4.2

Project->Edit Active Target (myTarget)->Base SDK->Latest SDK (4.2)
Project->Edit Active Target (myTarget)->iOS Target Deployment->iOS 4.2
```

And, If you still have problems:

Click the box that says base SDK missing, and select:

```
Simulator -> Debug
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for this. It was the Active Target that got me. What I did have to do however was to restart Xcode after changing this to get rid of the Base SDK not found thing...

Comment: I was going to add you might also have to reload the project (you don't have to restart XCode)

Comment: +1 for reloading the project. For whatever reason if I download sample apps from Apple while in XCode, I have to first change the SDK and then close the project and reopen it.

Comment: +1 for not needing to restart XCode, just **reload the project**! And "Simulator -> Debug" isn't always an option if the "Base SDK missing" actually insists in being there.

Comment: Also, when changing your settings, make sure you have selected **All Configuration** in the **Configuration** drop down.

Answer (score 4):

You can double-click or right-click on your target and pull up it's Info.  Click on the build tag and look for the setting for Base SDK.  You probably want this set to Latest iOS, which is a new option and should prevent this from happening the next time you upgrade.

However, you might be better off doing this at the Project level, by selecting Project -> Edit Project Settings and following the steps above.  You can also select the general tab under the project settings and set your Base SDK with the "Base SDK for all Configurations" drop down.  That has the advantage of fixing a problem that sometimes crops up with your linked frameworks (if they are all in red in the sidebar, you have the problem).

Comment: Thanks, I've come across the framework problems before. It was the active target that got me (see accepted answer) +1 Anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I found that, with Xcode 3.2.5 after setting the Base SDK to Latest iOS in the Project and Target Build info settings, quitting and restarting Xcode automatically got rid of the "Base Missing SDK" message in the select widget.

Comment: Yea thats what I ended up doing.

Comment: That fixed it for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you have to do:

Double click on the main project icon to open properties. 
Under the General tab, set "Base SDK for all configurations" to "Latest iOS".
Under Build tab, set Base SDK to the same thing.

Repeat this step for all framework projects under your main project.

Finally, and this is the bit I was missing for an annoying week or so, double-click your TARGET (under "Targets") and perform the same steps.

Things should be back to normal - and since "Latest iOS" should hopefully keep you updated with each new SDK released, you won't have to go through all that again.

Finally - restart Xcode or otherwise cause the project file to be reloaded.

Unless you work with people who haven't upgraded yet and persist in submitting changed project files. Apply a similar penalty as you would for breaking a build until they get it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

RESTarting is must folks .. if u won't restart your project (just close the project and then reopen it ) you will see the same thing " base sdk missing"... i also had the same trouble .. but restarting works..

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need to restart xCode, nor reopen your projects. Try this:

In the main project window, select Option-Cmd-E, choose build and "latest ios...".

Close the build window.

In the main project window, option-click the dropdown for Base SDK and you should see the latest build available.

Select that and you should be good to go.

Takes 5 seconds. I hope this helps..

Comment: Not tried this although closing and reopening also works! Takes roughly 5 seconds ;)

Answer (score -1):

This works fine for me. Just don't forget to restart Xcode.

Comment: As you can see from the tick above and my answer saying "Thanks", you can see it worked for me 12 days ago!