# “Base SDK Missing” after installing to Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, build, sdk

Hello
after installing xcode 4 preview 5 I've tried to build a project created with Xcode 3.2.3.
Unfortunately an error message is displayed:

> Missing SDK: There is no SDK with the name or path '/User/Me/Desktop/Project/IPhone4.0'

any idea to fix it?

thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know how different Xcode 4 is, but here is a related answer for Xcode 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340905/base-sdk-missing-after-upgrading-to-xcode-3-2-5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreed with Kristopher Jhonson. That should work.

Ref: ["Base SDK Missing" after upgrading to Xcode 3.2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340905/base-sdk-missing-after-upgrading-to-xcode-3-2-5)

```
Project->Edit Project Settings->Build->Base SDK->Latest SDK (4.2)
Project->Edit Project Settings->Build->iOS Target Deployment->iOS 4.2

Project->Edit Active Target (myTarget)->Base SDK->Latest SDK (4.2)
Project->Edit Active Target (myTarget)->iOS Target Deployment->iOS 4.2
```

And, If you still have problems:

Click the box that says base SDK missing, and select:

```
Simulator -> Debug
```

That should do it."

Answer (score 1):

These are due to inappropriate Base SDK selection for Project.
Follow these steps to resolve it :

1. Select Project
2. Build Setting
3. Base SDK -> Latest iOS SDK

[image]